# What free javascript IDEs support autocompletion for user defined variables, and "jump to definition"?

Tags: javascript, ide

I'm spoiled by Visual Studio (but looking for alternatives).
So in the example below, if I typed FirstCue. I'd like to see the members of that variable (FeedbackMild, etc.).

Also, I'd like to be able to jump to the definition of *FirstCue*.

So far, I've taken a look at NetBeans (it doesn't do the first, didn't go any further to see if it did the second)(.

```
function clsCues () {
    this.FeedbackMild=true ;  //boolean- whether we provide feedback to let them know if something is allowed or now (i.e., if they click on the wrong thing we'd do a Mild Feedback "ding"
    this.FeedbackCorrectIncorrect=true; //boolean -provide audio/visual feedback if their answer is correct
}

var FirstCue=new clsCues ();
    FirstCue.FeedbackMild=true;
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but Sublime Text 2 has a mini-preview that lets you scroll through the *entire* document in miniature form. When you highlight a variable, all of the occurrences of that variable show up as well and it's really easy to find things.

Comment: While it's specifically not an IDE, ST2 *is* quite good--and it *does* have completion, it's just not context-sensitive, and it'll only complete things in the same file. (This may be customizable, however; I haven't checked that out  yet.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO none of the free IDEs have particularly good JavaScript support.

[IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) has great [JavaScript](http://www.jetbrains.com/editors/javascript_editor.jsp?ide=idea) support. It's only free if you ask them for an OS license and they give it to you, though, which is why I'm still answering. (Plus it has the best JS support of any IDEs I've used.)

It will also highlight the suspicious usage of a non-capitalized constructor function.

(The Community Edition doesn't support JS editing according to their feature comparison matrix.)